# How to Create a global WH_GETMESSAGE HOOK without DLL

Tags: dll, windows-7, mfc, hook, global

I am trying to create a global WH_GETMESSAGE HOOK without DLL,but I can't success.
My OS is Win7 32Bit,This is my some code:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE,GetMsgProc,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);
```

Please help me if you have any time.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> hMod [in]
>
> Type: HINSTANCE
>
> A handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the lpfn parameter. The hMod parameter must be set to NULL if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process.

`hMod` *must* be a handle to a DLL. Not an EXE. This is because the DLL will be loaded into all running processes to be hooked, and its code run straight from within those processes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but it seems useless for me.

Comment: I think have other way to do.Thanks~.

Comment: @italkboy, you should write your alternate method as an answer so someone else with the same problem might be helped as well...

Comment: @italkboy, no problem then - it's just helpful to leave a hint to future travelers if you do find a solution :) The usual approach is to create a DLL specifically for the hook, btw.

Comment: Thanks for your attention,I will tell you after find solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need a message loop in the calling thread of SetWindowsHookEx

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious, the last parameter shouldn't be '0', it should be the thread id of the thread you want to call the function in. You can't pass in null for both the last and next to last parameters. Use GetThreadId() to get the id of the current thread, that's most likely what you want to do.

The previous poster's answer was very useful for you, if you would have read it you would have seen the above yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much,I have found a compromise,and I will try it again.:)